# Rounding a coordinate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I'm trying to combine animate's `\multiframe` command with a TikZ `\fill` command so that in every fourth frame, the top of my rectangle is moved by one unit:

```
\multiframe{20}{rya=10+-0.25}{
  \fill[green!10] (4,0) rectangle (6,\rya);
}
```

The problem with my current approach is that instead of resizing the rectangle by one unit every fourth frame, it gets resized by a *quarter* unit in *each* frame.

What I'm after is some kind of "floor" function that I could apply to `\rya`, or any kind of alternative way to achieve the same result.

(There are some other things being animated at the same time, preventing me from simply lowering the frame rate and using `iya=10+-1` instead of `rya=10+-0.25`. I left them out here for the sake of brevity.)

Comment: There is a built-in `floor` function in TikZ, so you *might* just be able to write `floor(\rya)`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson You may need some braces around that as well, `{floor(\rya)}`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get "undefined control sequence". Even leaving out the `\rya` part and simply trying the variation `(6,{floor(3.5)})` will give me that. I'm currenly only doing `\usepackage{tikz}`, so maybe I need to include something else?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, for example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0,0) rectangle +(1,{floor(1.9)});
  \fill (1.1,0) rectangle +(1,1.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works fine here. Could you create a complete, minimal example (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Alright, I'm an idiot. I must have kept messing up the syntax of `floor` but eventually got it right. Thanks a lot. Could someone please make this into an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `floor` function in PGF's math engine (see section **63.2 Functions** of the manual), and this can be used in TikZ coordinates, e.g.

```
\node at (1,{floor(1.6)}) {text};
```

will place a node at `(1,1)`. The braces surrounding `floor()` is necessary so that the closing parenthesis of `floor` isn't read as the closing parenthesis of the coordinate. Leaving them out will give an error.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\rya{1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle +(1,\rya);
\fill (1.1,0) rectangle +(1,{floor(\rya)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```